# Custom Calendar Display Form Not Showing Recurrence Data Correctly

Tags: calendar, form, display-form, recurring-events

Can someone please help and provide the details I need to be able to display the Recurrence Data correctly on a custom Display form (dispformcustom.aspx)?

The default dispform.aspx shows the recurrence data correctly. The issue happens when you create a custom dispform.aspx using SharePoint Designer. The recurrence field does not output correctly. It either shows a 0 or 1 or if you add @RecurrenceData it displays the data mixed together and not formatted correctly.

In Designer I've updated the Recurrence field to display @fRecurrence and @RecurrenceData, none of these options work.

Comment: The best I can get is in Designer is changing the field to @RecurrenceData and then format the column as Label and then can get it to display the data like the following:<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><daily dayFrequency="1" /></repeat><repeatInstances>3</repeatInstances></rule></recurrence>The default dispform.aspx displays this as:Every 1 day(s) That should be the correct way it should display.I really need this working and hoping someone can help! - See more at: http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/custom-calendar-display-form-not-25283.aspx#sthash.3KWlgR8g.dpuf

Comment: Are you good enough with XSL to do a few nested if statements... If the content inside the repeat tag is `<daily...>` then output `Repeat every [dayFrequency] Day(s)`, etc for weekly, monthly yearly.

Comment: To confirm what you need to do: you want to "parse" the xml recurrenceData information so that it gets displayed in the standard "human readable" format that SharePoint uses out of the box? I had a similar problem in the past and I think I may still have the (somehow horrid workaround) solution I used lingering somewhere.

Comment: Found: look at this one, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/event-splistitem-recurrence-text . I think those may be the info you require.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Can I put that script directly on the custom dispform.aspx otherwise where do I need to put that script to get it working correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: Erin L: Anyway you can provide me the XSL with nested statements to format and output the data correctly, like you mentioned above.  That would really help me out!  Let me know.  Thanks!